# A combinatorial identity in proving the Taylor expansion of the Spread Polynomials

Tags: combinatorics

In trying to prove the Taylor expansion of the Spread Polynomials as given ( also in Wikipedia ) by S Goh in a new way I miss a final decisive step. How to prove a combinatorial simplification for this sum ?

$$\sum_{k+l=i}\frac{2m+1}{2k+1}\frac{2m+1}{2l+1}\binom{m+k}{2k}\binom{m+l}{2l}$$

If I compare this expression with the one of Goh the result should be

$$\frac{2m+1}{i+1}\binom{2m+1+i}{2m-i}$$

Please rely not 100% on this expression of the result because I might have done an error in my modification of Goh result when making a comparison. But the form of the result should be correct : a factor times a binomial both dependent on the integer $i$. $m$ is also an integer.

Comment: The generating function of these coefficients is the square of the generating function of

$$
a_n=\frac{2m+1}{2n+1}\binom{m+n}{2n}
$$

Unfortunately, according to Wolfram|Alpha, a) this is not a terribly nice function, and b) the generating function for your second expression doesn't look like its square (but you said not to attach to much weight to this latter point).

Comment: @joriki I also thought this would be a hard problem. Meanwhile I tested the eqaution with CAS Maple and it resulted that it is 100% correct for $m=8$ and values $i$ in the range of $0$ to $16$.

Comment: @joriki a thought. If one would consider $$b_n=(2m+1)\binom{m+n}{2n}$$ then the $a_n$ reminds me on an integral formula because of the denominator $2n+1$ being $2n$ plus $1$.

Comment: @joriki: I've added an answer which could be of interest to you. Enjoy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:**  We prove OPs identity and reveal a  strong connection with *[Chebyshev  polynomials of the  first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)*.  At the end some information is added which shows how this relationship was found and a small challenge related with OPs expression is formulated.

We start with OPs claim.

> The following holds true for $m,n\geq 0, n\leq 2m$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\frac{2m+1}{2k+1}\frac{2m+1}{2l+1}\binom{m+k}{2k}\binom{m+l}{2l}
> =\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\binom{2m+n+1}{2m-n}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We write $n$ instead of $i$ to avoid conflicts with the imaginery unit (which will be used later). Denoting the left hand sum in (1) with $S_{m,n}$, we can write it in the form

> \begin{align*}
> S_{m,n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2m+1}{2k+1}\binom{m+k}{2k}\frac{2m+1}{2n-2k+1}\binom{m+n-k}{2n-2k}
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **First step:** Generating functions
>
> Setting  $a_k=\frac{2m+1}{2k+1}\binom{m+k}{2k}$    we  see that $S_{m,n}$ is a Cauchyprodukt of  the $a_k$
>   \begin{align*}
> S_{m,n}=\sum_{k=0}^na_ka_{n-k}
> \end{align*}
>   Since this typically occurs when multiplying series we use the Ansatz
>   \begin{align*}
> A_m(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{2m+1}{2k+1}\binom{m+k}{2k}x^{2k}\qquad\qquad m\geq 0
> \end{align*}

The binomial coefficient with $2k$ recommends to take even powers of $x$ and since $\binom{m+k}{2k}=0$ for $k>m$ we restrict the upper limit of the index with $m$.

> We observe
>   \begin{align*}
> A_m^2(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^{2k}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}a_lx^{2l}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_ka_{n-k}\right)x^{2n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}S_{m,n}x^{2n}
> \end{align*}
>
> Next we focus on
>   \begin{align*}
> A_m(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{2m+1}{2k+1}\binom{m+k}{2k}x^{2k}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

We derive now a striking relationship with

> **Second step:** Chebyshev polynomials $T_m(x)$ of the first kind
>
> The *[Wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)* states besides other identities for the *Chebyshev polynomial* $T_m(x)$ of the first kind
>   \begin{align*}
> T_m(x)=\frac{m}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\right\rfloor}(-1)^k\frac{(m-k-1)!}{k!(m-2k)!}(2x)^{m-2k}\qquad\qquad m>0
> \end{align*}
>   We derive for odd $2m+1$
>   \begin{align*}
> T_{2m+1}(x)&=\frac{2m+1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^k\frac{(2m-k)!}{k!(2m-2k+1)!}(2x)^{2m+1-2k}\qquad\qquad m\geq 0\\
> &=\frac{2m+1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^{m-k}\frac{(m+k)!}{(m-k)!(2k+1)!}(2x)^{2k+1}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^m}{2i}\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{2m+1}{2k+1}\binom{m+k}{2k}(2ix)^{2k+1}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we reorder the sum by changing the index $k \rightarrow m-k$
- In (4) we rewrite the expression to make it easy to compare it with $A_m(x)$. Here we use the imaginery unit $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

> Now we can write $A_m(x)$ in terms of Chebyshev polynomials. This brings us in the convenient position to use the numerous relationships which are fulfilled by these *[orthogonal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials)*.
>
> We observe when looking at the representation (2) of $A_m(x)$ and (4)
>
> \begin{align*}
> A_m(x)=(-1)^m\frac{2i}{x}T_{2m+1}\left(-\frac{i}{2}x\right)\qquad\qquad m\geq 0
> \end{align*}
>
> We use the *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series. We can write $S_{m,n}$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> S_{m,n}&=[x^{2n}]A_m^2(x)\\
> &=[x^{2n}]\frac{-4}{x^2}T_{2m+1}^2\left(-\frac{i}{2}x\right)\\
> &=-4[x^{2n+2}]T_{2m+1}^2\left(-\frac{i}{2}x\right)\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>
> Next we can replace the square $T_{2m+1}^2(x)$ by a simpler expression due to the nice relationships that orthogonal polynomials fulfill. We use the following identity which is also stated in the Wiki page.
>
> \begin{align*}
> T_m(x)T_n(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(T_{m+n}(x)+T_{|m-n|}\right)\qquad\qquad \forall m,n\geq 0
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain from it
>   \begin{align*}
> T_{2m+1}^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(T_{4m+2}(x)+T_0(x)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(T_{4m+2}(x)+1\right)\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

We observe, that we can replace the square of the Chebyshev  polynomial $T_{2m+1}(x)$ by an expression containing a *linear term* $T_{4m+2}(x)$. This way we will be able to reduce the combinatorial expression $S_{m,n}$ with a simpler closed formula.

To calculate $T_{4m+2}(x)$ we proceed similarly as in (3),(4) and we obtain

\begin{align*}
T_{2m}(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{m-k}\frac{m}{m+k}\binom{m+k}{2k}(2x)^{2k}\\
T_{4m+2}(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{2m+1}(-1)^{2m+1-k}\frac{2m+1}{2m+1+k}\binom{2m+1+k}{2k}(2x)^{2k}\tag{7}
\end{align*}

> Proceeding with (5) we finally obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> S_{m,n}&=-4[x^{2n+2}]T_{2m+1}^2\left(-\frac{i}{2}x\right)\\
> &=-2[x^{2n+2}]T_{4m+2}\left(-\frac{i}{2}x\right)\tag{8}\\
> &=-2[x^{2n+2}]\sum_{k=0}^{2m+1}(-1)^{2m+1-k}\frac{2m+1}{2m+1+k}\binom{2m+1+k}{2k}(-ix)^{2k}\tag{9}\\
> &=2\frac{2m+1}{2m+n+2}\binom{2m+n+2}{2n+2}\tag{10}\\
> &=2\frac{2m+1}{2n+2}\binom{2m+n+1}{2n+1}\tag{11}\\
> &=\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\binom{2m+n+1}{2m-n}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (8) we use the product formula (6). Note, that according to the coefficient $[x^{2n+2}]$ we can ignore the constant part $T_0(x)=1$ from (6).
- In (9) we use the calculation (7)
- In (10) we extract the relevant coefficient with $k=n+1$.
- In (11) we use $\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k}$

**Epilog:** At the beginning the connection with the Chebyshev polynomials was not obvious for me. When looking at
\begin{align*}
A(x)=(2m+1)\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{m+k}{2k}x^{2k}
\end{align*}
the strategy was to integrate and to further simplify. So I considered
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2m+1}\frac{1}{x}&\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{m+k}{2k}x^{2k+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2m+1}\frac{1}{x}\int\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m+k}{2k}x^{2k}\,dx
\end{align*}

The next step was to find the generating function for
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m+k}{2k}x^{2k}\tag{12}
\end{align*}

I typed in for small values of $m=3,4$ the coefficients $1,5,6,1;1,7,15,10,1$ into *[OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C6%2C5%2C1%3B1%2C10%2C15%2C7%2C1&sort=&language=english&go=Search)*
and it returned besides others the sequence $A129818$ which contains  a reference to Chebyshev polynomials somewhere.

This information directed me to the *Chebyshev polynomials* $U_n(x)$ of the *second kind*. Observe, that my input to OEIS was (12) which is an expression *without* the factor $\frac{1}{2k+1}$.

But since the polynomials of the first and second kind are strongly related e.g. via
\begin{align*}
\int U_n(x)\,dx=\frac{T_{n+1}(x)}{n+1}\tag{13}
\end{align*}

I decided to present the somewhat shorter way and started directly from the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.

> **Small challenge:**
>
> The relationship (13) and the structure of $S_{m,n}$ invites to look for an identity similar to OPs expression. Find a closed formula with $m,n\geq 0$ for
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\binom{m+k}{2k}\binom{m+l}{2l}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Heaven ! How many weeks moths years do you think i will need to study & understand this all "en detail" ?... ;) GREAT ! Thanks for your deep interest in this problem.

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann: :-) I hope you enjoy the answer. I was rather lengthy       with my elaborations, so that it shouldn't be too hard to follow the gory details. Just ask, if you encounter problems. Regards,

Comment: Almost I got it. But I cant see how you derived the last equation just after (10). I dont see how the factor $2$ cancels. This $$\binom{2m+n+2}{2n+2}=\binom{2m+n+2}{2m-n}$$ I understand. But why appears the denominator $n+1$ ?

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann: You're speedy!  :-) Typo fixed, thanks!  One  line (11) added.

Comment: Its not so hard to be speedy if the proof is given in such an exemplary way. Finally I met someone who doesnt make a puzzle book of mathematics. May be your way of presentation a "Vorbild" ( engl: example ) for every writer of mathematical texts.

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann: My pleasure! Thank you very much for your extraordinary nice comment.

Comment: Let me add a remark about Lemma 95 in the thesis of S Goh about the Spread Polynomials $S_n(x)$. The connection to the Chebyshev Polynomials of the second kind might be because of the formula $$S_n(s)=sU_{n-1}^2(\sqrt{1-s})$$

Comment: Isnt there a typo in equation (1) in the second binomial where instead of $2m$ there should be only $m$. ?!!

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann: Thanks for your good review! Typos corrected in (1) as well as in the *small challenge* section.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k+l=i}\frac{2m+1}{2k+1}\frac{2m+1}{2l+1}\binom{m+k}{2k}\binom{m+l}{2l}$$

We have the obvious constraints $k, l \ge 0$, which we can rewrite (substituting $l = i - k$) as $0 \le k \le i$. The numerators of the two fractions can be pulled out as independent of $k$, so we have

$$(2m+1)^2 \sum_{k=0}^i\frac{(m+k)!(m+i-k)!}{(m-k)!(2k+1)!(m-i+k)!(2i-2k+1)!}$$

Wolfram Alpha (probably using Zeilberger's method) evaluates that sum as $$-\frac{(-1)^i 4^{1-i} m(m+1)(1-2m)_{i-1} (2m+3)_{i-1}}{3\left(\frac52\right)_{i-1}(3)_{i-1}}$$

where $(a)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol: $(a)_n = a(a+1)\ldots(a+n-1)$. For positive $a$ and $n$ we have $(a)_n = \frac{(a+n-1)!}{(a-1)!}$, but we need to tread a bit more carefully with the first one in the numerator:

$$\begin{eqnarray}(-1)^{i-1} (-b)_{i-1} & = & (-1)^{i-1} (-b)(-b+1)\ldots(-b+i-2) \\
& = & (b)(b-1)\ldots(b-i+2)
\end{eqnarray}$$

So putting back in the $(2m+1)^2$ and expanding to factorials we have the original sum as

$$\begin{eqnarray}&\frac{4^{1-i} m(m+1)(2m+1)^2 \frac{(2m-1)!}{(2m-i)!}  \frac{(2m+i+1)!}{(2m+2)!}}{3 \left(\frac52\right)\ldots\left(\frac12 + i\right)  \frac{(i+1)!}{2!}}\\
= & \frac{(2m+1) (2m+i+1)!}{3 \cdot 2^i (2m-i)! \left(5 \cdot 7 \cdots(1 + 2i)\right) (i+1)!} \\
= & \frac{(2m+1) (2m+i+1)!}{2^i (2m-i)! (2i + 1)!! (i+1)!} \\
= & \frac{2m+1}{i+1} \binom{2m+i+1}{2m-i}
\end{eqnarray}$$

as desired.

Comment: But in my view it looks probably fine. 1st Q: is the !! in the denominator a typo ? 2nd R: if one multiplies numer and denom simply by $$2\cdot 4\cdots \cdot 2i$$ it looks splendid - the $2^i$ cancels ( what it should ) and also $i!$ cancels and $i+1$ stays there as it should.

Comment: 1. Not a typo: the $!!$ is a [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html). 2. You're quite right. I've edited.

Comment: @PeterTayler: I've added an answer which might be of interest for you. Regards,